# changing the points on a ggplot to colours based on a categorical factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to improve my `ggplot` created with `small_multiple` from the `dotwhisker`package. I am happy enough with the plot as it is but would like to change the colours to indicate the significance of the effect sizes and supply a legend.

Here is a link to the dataframe I am using to plot https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gCpGtK8bJxZ_niMytXar5_mjEKh3ywo0

and the `dput` output

```
structure(list(term = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Age of householder", 
"Resident", "Household size", "Receives remitances", "External income", 
"Number of Dependents", "Wealth Quartile (linear)"), class = "factor"), 
    estimate = c(-0.000810532238065848, 0.0254269932291557, 0.00151239486806329, 
    -0.00195137580266825, 0.0241145273101975, 7.89713470909372e-05, 
    0.0431864414315616, -0.000352189998018801, 0.0807237065792145, 
    0.00350237566205939, 0.0824016056908091, 0.000428245312902082, 
    0.00100203882798397, -0.00373159468619221, -0.00849653886442907, 
    -0.373953842018999, -0.0609596475582067, -0.36695400544924, 
    -0.203483373342371, 0.0235518405167902, 0.597075641980254, 
    0.000909859014488281, 0.0319827360659694, 0.00403573196123029, 
    0.0804028888279925, 0.0176817124413346, -0.00582802408980782, 
    -0.0118019232578557, -0.00183146459363335, 0.0525149485157465, 
    0.00288980763951367, 0.114589339700339, -0.148808706655833, 
    0.0256886983033479, -0.0347089125407724), std.error = c(0.000810654234866564, 
    0.0252884817638327, 0.00495624457235766, 0.02865293313387, 
    0.024633101790692, 0.0075249698129155, 0.011074940767766, 
    0.0015232885358452, 0.0483657672257486, 0.0107841171733555, 
    0.0465110585212233, 0.0453369280370182, 0.0159322010498352, 
    0.0229851941101918, 0.00503353340127795, 0.160380043957635, 
    0.0336136390831826, 0.177927931390999, 0.157637829739609, 
    0.0502799707398752, 0.0734336375273297, 0.00155887187625948, 
    0.0506436749394975, 0.00906123485748438, 0.0593975064913416, 
    0.0512499791059356, 0.0149811592829444, 0.0215922521880395, 
    0.00519154572969568, 0.168543739122589, 0.0312059226076805, 
    0.181305323277894, 0.172221721744089, 0.048730984968198, 
    0.0723545683575288), statistic = c(-0.999849508217599, 1.00547725508461, 
    0.305149361776521, -0.0681038759121512, 0.978948064076507, 
    0.0104945732746189, 3.89947380642044, -0.231203734375501, 
    1.66902566028642, 0.324771662414126, 1.77165621060223, 0.00944583877744019, 
    0.0628939356746528, -0.162347756051257, -1.68798698390914, 
    -2.3316731482988, -1.81353906393032, -2.06237437023226, -1.29082830992085, 
    0.468413966241872, 8.13081936405562, 0.583665039022637, 0.631524787728739, 
    0.445384323958546, 1.35364081048946, 0.345009163902015, -0.389023571523124, 
    -0.54658139202325, -0.352778283962203, 0.311580535646894, 
    0.0926044608853327, 0.632024132709568, -0.864053065715796, 
    0.527153274659078, -0.479705889049931), p.value = c(0.317383342554256, 
    0.314667096264215, 0.760252397576013, 0.945702944991097, 
    0.327605641839857, 0.991626695712718, 9.64019651538276e-05, 
    0.817156528984679, 0.0951122945259745, 0.745353893046104, 
    0.0764516427435714, 0.992463423149573, 0.949850963916399, 
    0.871032009571373, 0.0914137275496443, 0.0197178924481877, 
    0.0697487192470644, 0.0391721074734652, 0.196763218800044, 
    0.639488582387532, 4.26398344685646e-16, 0.559445693078128, 
    0.527697446929629, 0.656042038835549, 0.175851000195762, 
    0.730087481451201, 0.697258709585814, 0.584666355951097, 
    0.724254665274968, 0.755359328643605, 0.926217799705955, 
    0.527371108047216, 0.387558740148672, 0.598087153395465, 
    0.631436539811527), model = c("Dietary diversity", "Dietary diversity", 
    "Dietary diversity", "Dietary diversity", "Dietary diversity", 
    "Dietary diversity", "Dietary diversity", "Food security \n(Cond)", 
    "Food security \n(Cond)", "Food security \n(Cond)", "Food security \n(Cond)", 
    "Food security \n(Cond)", "Food security \n(Cond)", "Food security \n(Cond)", 
    "Food security \n(Zinf)", "Food security \n(Zinf)", "Food security \n(Zinf)", 
    "Food security \n(Zinf)", "Food security \n(Zinf)", "Food security \n(Zinf)", 
    "Food security \n(Zinf)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Cond)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)", "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)", 
    "Vegetable consumption \n(Zinf)"), Significance = c("non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "< 0.05", "non-significant", 
    "< 0.1", "non-significant", "< 0.1", "non-significant", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "< 0.1", "< 0.05", "< 0.1", "< 0.05", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "< 0.05", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant", "non-significant", "non-significant", 
    "non-significant")), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("term", 
"estimate", "std.error", "statistic", "p.value", "model", "Significance"
))
```

I think from what I have read that perhaps the problem is that you can't have more than one aesthetic or a discrete and a continuous color designation based on some of the errors I have encountered whilst looking for a workaround.

Here is the code to generate the plot so far

```
small_multiple(stack_mods_dummys)+
ylab("Coefficient Estimate") +
geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey60", linetype = 2) +
theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,vjust = 0.5))+
facet_wrap(~term,nrow = 5, scales = "free_y")
```

Essentially I want the dots and whiskers to be coloured according to the variable `Significance` in the dataframe with a legend showing the three factor levels

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been banging my head against a wall for quite a while now on this and I'm sure there must be an existing solution out there.

Comment: Please put a representative sample of your data directly in the post, preferably the output of `dput`, so people don't have to download a file from a separate source

Comment: @camille, I have added the `dput` output. Thought that the download might be easier but point taken and will use `dput` from now on.